# Get list of data-foo attributes for set of jQuery elements

Tags: jquery, each

I can use `attr` to "Get the value of an attribute for the **first element** in the set of matched elements ..."

To get the list of attributes, do I need to build it up manually with `$(..).each` or is there a convenience?

```
$('tr.food-row')
[
<tr class=​"food-row" data-pk=​"11457">​…​</tr>​
, 
<tr class=​"food-row" data-pk=​"11429">​…​</tr>​
]
$('tr.food-row').attr('data-pk')
"11457"
```

I want to get `["11457", "11429"]`.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
var allAttributes = $('tr.food-row').map(function(){
    return $(this).data('pk');
}).get();
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WuJHP/)

Comment: why the `get()` call?

Comment: @SkylarSaveland. _"As the return value is a jQuery object, which contains an array, it's very common to call .get() on the result to work with a basic array."_ [docs](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

Comment: you don't like the `potato-programming` tag on this question?

Comment: @SkylarSaveland, well... since this was the only question in that tag... and nobody uses that phrase... and it's a simple jQuery API question... I think we better without it, but you can return it if you like, it's your question after all.

Comment: I just think it's a shame so few use the phrase potato programming :D